# Cron Job doesn't work on CPanle using Laravel Project

Tags: laravel, cpanel, cron-task

I'm trying to run a schedule task on cpanel.

So I'm using the following code :

Command : notify.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Console\Commands;

use Illuminate\Console\Command;
use App\Mail\NotifyContratExpire;
use Mail;
use Carbon\Carbon;
use App\Models\Projet_Casting;
use App\Models\Filiale;
class notify extends Command
{
    /**
     * The name and signature of the console command.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $signature = 'emails:send';

    /**
     * The console command description.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $description = 'Send Emails notify to all users for contrats expirés';

    /**
     * Create a new command instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }

    /**
     * Execute the console command.
     *
     * @return int
     */
    public function handle()
    {

       

          $today_date = Carbon::now()->addDays(60);
                    $contrat_email = Projet_Casting::join('contrats','contrats.id_contrat','=','projets_castings.id_contrat')->leftjoin('projets','projets.id_projet','=','projets_castings.id_projet')->join('castings','castings.id_casting','=','contrats.id_casting')->join('filiales','projets.id_filiale','=','filiales.id_filiale')->where('contrats.actif',1)->where('contrats.date_fin_contrat', '<=', $today_date)->distinct('filiales.id_filiale')->get();
                  $emails = array();
                 foreach($contrat_email as $key) {
                   $emails[] = json_decode($key->adm_email);
                   
                  }
                   $email_send = array();
                    foreach ($emails as $key3 => $value) {
                       $filiale =Filiale::where('adm_email', json_encode($value))->select('filiales.id_filiale')->value('filiales.id_filiale');
                
                      $contras = Projet_Casting::join('contrats','contrats.id_contrat','=','projets_castings.id_contrat')->leftjoin('projets','projets.id_projet','=','projets_castings.id_projet')->join('castings','castings.id_casting','=','contrats.id_casting')->where('contrats.actif',1)->where('contrats.date_fin_contrat', '<=', $today_date)->where('projets.id_filiale',$filiale)->get();
                  
                     
                     foreach($value as $val =>$v){          
                       Mail::to($v)->send(new NotifyContratExpire($contras));
                      }
                     }

                }
           

          }
```

MailController : NotifyContratExpire

```
<?php
namespace App\Mail;
use Illuminate\Bus\Queueable;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldQueue;
use Illuminate\Mail\Mailable;
use Illuminate\Queue\SerializesModels;

class NotifyContratExpire extends Mailable
{
    use Queueable, SerializesModels;


    public $contras;
    /**
     * Create a new message instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct($contras)
    {
        $this->contras = $contras;

    }

    /**
     * Build the message.
     *
     * @return $this
     */
    public function build()
    {
        return $this->subject("contrats")->view('Template_Mails.template_email')->with('contras',$this->contras);
    }
}
```

And kernel.php :

```
<?php

namespace App\Console;

use Illuminate\Console\Scheduling\Schedule;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Console\Kernel as ConsoleKernel;
use Mail;
use Illuminate\Console\Command;
use App\Mail\NotifyContratExpire;
use Carbon\Carbon;
use App\Models\Projet_Casting;
class Kernel extends ConsoleKernel
{
    /**
     * The Artisan commands provided by your application.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $commands = [
        /*'\App\Console\Commands\notify'*/
        Commands\notify::class,
    ];

    /**
     * Define the application's command schedule.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Console\Scheduling\Schedule  $schedule
     * @return void
     */
    protected function schedule(Schedule $schedule)
    {
        // $schedule->command('inspire')->hourly();
          $schedule->command('emails:send')->everyMinute()->withoutOverlapping(60);

    }

    /**
     * Register the commands for the application.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    protected function commands()
    {
        $this->load(__DIR__.'/Commands');

        require base_path('routes/console.php');
    }
}
```

And the email view :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
   <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="row">


                 <table class="data-table data-table-standard responsive nowrap"
                                data-order="[[ 1, &quot;desc&quot; ]]">
                                <thead>
                                    <tr>
                                        <th>numero_contrat</th>
                                        <th>numero_projet</th>
                                        <th>casting</th>
                                        <th>casting</th>
                                    </tr>
                                </thead>
                                <tbody>
                                    @foreach($contras as $contra) 
                                        <tr>
                                            <td>
                                                <p class="list-item-heading">{{$contra->numero_contrat}}</p>
                                            </td>
                                            <td>
                                                <p class="text-muted">{{$contra ->numero_projet}}</p>
                                            </td>
                                            <td>
                                                <p class="text-muted">{{$contra->nom}}</p>
                                            </td>
                                            <td>
                                                <p class="text-muted">{{$contra->prenom}}</p>
                                            </td>
                                        </tr>
                                       @endforeach
                                    

                                </tbody>
                            </table>
            
            </div>

        </div>
</body>
</html>
```

On cpanel I have the following structure :

[image]

And I created a cron JOV for everyMinute with the following command :

```
/usr/local/bin/php /home/current_user/laravel/artisan schedule:run
```

the mails are not sent and I do not know where the error is or how to display the errors to know how to solve this problem, when I run the execution in localhost, it works very well and the emails are sent.

If you have any idea , please help

Answer (score 2):

You can try this

```
/path/to/php /path-to-your-project/artisan schedule:run >>/dev/null 2>&1
```